# What does (|/)$ do with mod_rewrite?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've seen examples in htaccess files using mod_rewrite where everything is done through one php file and different URLs are redirected back to index php.

```
RewriteRule ^registration(|/)$ /index.php
```

I'm curious as to what `(|/)$` does/is. I've read a lot of stuff and can't seem to find any mention of the use of a vertical bar in mod_rewrite and if I remove this, the redirect still works fine.

Comment: This question doesn't actually have anything to do with PHP. I'm removing the tag. If someone disagrees, feel free to roll it back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The vertical bar stands for a logical `OR`, and lets you specify either a trailing slash after 'registration' or not.

I prefer using a '?' after the slash, making it optional:

```
RewriteRule ^registration/?$ /index.php
```

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought but then how come when I remove that regex, the redirect still works fine with or without the slash?

Comment: If you use only `registration` then it works as well, yes, but also for `registration1`, `registration/abc/` and similar. You need the `$` to mark the end of the url, and then trailing slashes would not match if the `/?` is omitted.

Comment: Deleted my last comment. I understand what you mean about the end of the URL now.

Comment: I'll add this link here, https://regex101.com/r/bN6jY9/2. That shows what matches and gives explanations of the parts.